# CSS - How to select multiple attribute values?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have multiple div tags with an attribute containing different numbered values, and I would like to select only number 1 through 10, what is the most efficient way to do this in css?

Is there anything like e.g. `.div[line-number=1-10]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in the standard CSS. It is convenient to use a CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) which allow you creating loops among many other features. An example with SASS:

```scss
$selector: '.div';
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
    $selector: $selector + '[line-number=' + $i + ']';
}

#{$selector} {
    // style
}
```

In pure CSS you are doomed to use this solution instead:

```
.div[line-number=1], .div[line-number=2], .div[line-number=3], .div[line-number=4], .div[line-number=5], .div[line-number=6], .div[line-number=7], .div[line-number=8], .div[line-number=9], .div[line-number=10] {
}
```

Comment: You _could_ use `.div[line-number^="*"]` but that would select every number, above 10 as well.

Comment: You forgot commas and dots in css solution.

Comment: Luckily my project was LESS based all along, so this helped immensely, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

if you have the ability to modify the line-number attribute starting with 0 (01,02,03,04...10) you can do this:

```
div[line-number^="0"], div[line-number="10"] {
  // css properties
}
```

if not see the answer from @jackBauer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify line-number in range (1-10).

This is not available in attribute selector - https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors.

But alternatively you can apply css on each attribute value with something like below

```css
div[line-number="1"] {
  color: red;
}

div[line-number="10"] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Use attribute selectors</p>

<div line-number="1">one</div>
<div line-number="2">two</div>
<div line-number="10">ten</div>
```

Hope this will help in some way(y).