# How to change the display attributes of SPECIFIC tabs when using tabPanel in navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny, navbar, tabpanel

In this example,

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = 'text/css', HTML('.navbar {background-color: red;}')),
  navbarPage("",
    tabPanel("Tab 1", icon = icon("user")),
    tabPanel("Tab 2", icon = icon("cog")),
    tabPanel("Tab 3", icon = icon("sliders"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like `Tab 3` to be special such that it appears different from the rest for:

- background-color + font-color when not hovered and not selected
- background-color + font-color when hovered
- background-color + font-color when selected
- Bolded font

For the other tabs, I am fine with sticking to the defaults.

None of the threads I came across directly address this issue for me, who has no HTML or CSS background. Some addressed part of the problem for `tabsetPanel`, but not for `navbarPage`.

Any advice, or redirection to a tutorial for dummies would be nice enough.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025145/background-color-of-tabs-in-shiny-tabpanel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
#select more than one Tab you can try
#1. a[data-value='Tab 2'], a[data-value='Tab 3'] {...}
#2. rename Tab 2 and Tab 3 values to Tab 02 and Tab 03 then use a[data-value*='0'] {...}
ui <- fluidPage(
       tags$style(type = 'text/css', 
                  HTML(".container-fluid > .nav > li > 
                        a[data-value='Tab 3'] {background-color: red; color:white}")),
    navbarPage("",
         tabPanel("Tab 1" ,value = "Tab 1" ,icon = icon("user")),
         tabPanel("Tab 2" ,value = "Tab 2" ,icon = icon("cog")),
         tabPanel("Tab 3" ,value = "Tab 3" ,icon = icon("sliders"))
   )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: A. Suliman, this was super helpful - thanks! Do you know if it would be possible to target two specific tabs at once (i.e. data-value = 'Tab 3' & 'Tab4'? I've been trying to figure it out, but so far have to separate the css code for the two into two different lines.

Comment: @seabass20 you're welcome, try one of the solutions proposed here [CSS - How to select multiple attribute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41137880/css-how-to-select-multiple-attribute-values)

Comment: Here another useful link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/

Comment: Perfect, those definitely helped! Thanks again!